# Firefox modo app

Tags: firefox

Utilizando el comando de chrome -app me abre el navegador simulando una aplicación (sin la barra de navegación, herramientas ...)¿Es posible obtener esto en firefox? (la versión que utilizo actualmente es la 49)

Comment: mirate de empaquetar la web como si fuese una webapp para firefox, se te creará un .exe y asi ejecutar solo tu app dentro de firefox

Answer (score 1):

en Firefox no existe tal comando pero está la opción de verlo tipo móvil entrando a **Herramientas** -> **Desarrollador Web** -> **Vista diseño adaptable**.

Saludos.